# Dynamic Role Hierarchy in Spring Security

Tags: dynamic, spring-security, hierarchy, roles

I can't believe all I find to define role hierarchies is some strange .xml notation of ">" assignments. There has to be a way to create a RoleHierarchy object from a database defined role hierarchy.. ?!

I'm thinking of a table that has the columns:

- role_id
- child_role_id

defining a many-to-many relationship between Role and Role saying: which role has which children? I think I'd prefer children over parents as that's the way the hierarchy is set up in those .xml files: ADMIN > USER, USER > VISITOR.

(This by the way makes me wonder if the standard implementation also supports things like ADMIN > USER, VISITOR meaning USER and VISITOR are "on the same level".)

Now if I want to call

```
roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities()));
```

I need a RoleHierarchy Implementation object. spring-security provides one but the setter accepts only this weird string representation. I don't really want to transform my database results into a string representation but rather work with some kind of tree structure.

So the only way seems to be extending the Implementation and writing my own setter to work with my database result set to build the `rolesReachableInOneStepMap` and `rolesReachableInOneOrMoreStepMap`.

Or does anyone know of a different solution?

Thanks for any pointers or confirmation!

Comment: what is the problem in extending Spring's implementation and write your own setter? I don't see any.

Comment: Yeah, I implemented my own version of RoleHierarchy. But I am still wondering about this strange String format. I guess there's just no alternative.

Comment: This is a little late, but what you were wondering works as of spring-security 4.0.0. i.e. A > B, A > C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We came up with our own solution by implementing `RoleHierarchy`, resolving the hierarchy inside the `UserDetailsService` and using a m:n self referencing relationship between `Role` and `Role`. 
The hierarchy is thus saved in the database, cached at application launch, updated when needed and used to resolve all `GrantedAuthorities` when creating a UserDetails object on login.

Comment: Awesame. Any code to share...?